# Ideal way to tackle pending data changes (when to save changes)?

Tags: android, database, mvvm

*I have a rather peculiar case on my hands, and Im surprised that noone seems to have written about it/something similar for Android (or my Google skills suck)*

---

**Situation #1:**

- User can input text into field1 and field2.
- User can also re-arrange items in a list (displayed in a `RecyclerView`)

Whenever the user does any of the edits, the UI is already showing the updated data (e.g. editing field1 will show the text as the user types it, and the list of items will show them in the new order as the user re-arranges them).

Saving the data right away here will trigger the UI to refresh (to display the same thing) and give the user a bad experience (field1 focus will shift to the first letter, and the app might crash if the user quickly re-arranges list items).

So it makes sense to store the edits and execute them at a later point.

---

**Situation #2:**

- User can tap plus/minus buttons to increase/decrease a value
- User can input text into field3.

As in situation #1 above, editing the field will already have the UI in the updated state. But, in this case - tapping the plus/minus button will also update the data, but the UI will not be updated (unless the data is saved, and the query ran again...).

---

**Problem:**

- If data is saved immediately as the user performs an edit, besides doing a lot of saves, it makes for a bad user experience as the UI will refresh in some cases whereas its already up to date.
- If the edits are tucked away and performed at a later point, the UI wont refresh.

Im using MVVM, so all performed actions are sent to the viewmodel and it decides what to do. I find myself looking for a solution that works differently across different screens of the app, but I know that would just be shooting myself in the foot and then jumping off a bridge. Surely, there must be someone out there that has come across this challenge and had some insights around it?

**Ideal solution:** One solution that *just works* for all the different screens. Do you have it? Please let me know.

*/ Desperate Android Dev*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me start by stating that I don't think there is a correct answer here, but you should consider what your own app does and then determine what you need to do.

Let me explain. Consider two application, one that saves TODO items and the other is a banking application.

I will now explain what I think could work for your application, since you have not mentioned explicitly any requirements that contradicts that.

In situations like that, I believe being **optimistic** is a good idea. Assuming that things will not fail, and when they do, try to back out. What does that mean?

That means, for example, in the scenario you mentioned, user enters something in a field. You should let the UI update automatically (Nothing we do here, that's just Android), when that happens you save those changes either locally, or to a server, doesn't matter.

Of course, you can optimize, instead of saving each letter, throttle the input somehow, but you get the idea.

This can either be a succeed or a failure, because we are optimistic, we let the UI update and the user get the feel that our application is lighting fast. You don't need to reload anything, or refresh anything. The UI should match your `Model` state now already.

What if the things go south, and your HTTP request or DB update fails for some reason, then you need to take action. But try to keep your reaction appropriate.

You can handle that failure in so many ways, again, depending on how critical what you are doing in your app really is.

- You can just show a Toast, or even do nothing if the user action was so trivial.
- You can show the user something a bit more concrete if the action is of some significance, maybe a Snakbar with retry and explanation of what happened.
- You kill your process and finish all activities -*kidding don't ever do that*- but showing a very intrusive pop-up and possibly reverting the UI value to the correct one, if what the user was doing is quite critical.

Now this approach doesn't just give the feel that the app is really fast, but it also keeps things simple.

Another advise is don't try to solve problems that don't exist yet, that means don't start implementing background services and job queues for some local persistence jobs that never outlive a view, and could never will.

Instead, use measurements, log those errors and failures with some tool, and use those stats to know what needs to be fixed -if any-

Back to our two applications, this approach might be perfect for a TODO app, however this might not be too good for a banking app.

Assume the user transfers money, we say immediately, ALL GOOD MATE! and then the request fails and your user's landlord kicks him out for never paying rent.

So it all comes to how sensitive the operations your're doing.

Comment: Thank you! I remember reading your answer last night shortly before closing down shop for the day, and I managed to sort the challenge out this morning by having the viewmodel produce a viewstate, that in turn accepts events (e.g. field1 changed, so the model is up to date with the UI as well) and behind the scenes all edits are stored as before and saved when the user clicks save. If anyone else stumbles across this, heres another answer that also provided some insight into this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362786/how-does-validating-and-saving-data-in-wpf-mvvm-work-right